# Excel calculation and output for date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have traveling data for journey start and journey end in custom format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM and i have to calculate the time difference in third column that to display only year within that.

I am applying simple calculation =journey end date - journey start date to calculate the difference and when i apply Time/custom format to display the year it shows 1900 as after calculation the value evaluation for year becomes 0 or 1 in both cases it display the output as 1900 i.e. year value from Excel first date 01-01-1900. though the values i have in journey start date is from year 2019 and journey end date is 2020.

Comment: Then what will be your result? Show data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell/column for output, and apply Formulas -> Date & Time -> Year function
i.e. =YEAR(Cellreference) in which year output will be taken from cellreference given in the function.